# Guess the book character

Tags: riddle, knowledge, no-computers

> His raiment was the color of the king of Doriath's cloak,
>   But now is the color of the Spirit of Fire's prized creations.
>   His weapon is from that which was betrayed by the Child of Twilight.
>   His lords far outnumber his peers-
>   -Them being only the Giver of Gifts and Aiwendil.
>
> Now who could it be, tell me that?
>   And may the wind under your wings bear you
>   Where the sun sails and the moon walks.

Find the quote in the "riddle", and figure out who said it.
*(Don't use the web to solve this puzzle. That would spoil the fun.)*

Comment: " And may the wind under your wings bear you " tells me that it is a bird.... is it so ? :)

Comment: Isn't it more of a trivia than a puzzle? Basically if we don't read the same books as you, we don't have a chance of knowing.

Comment: @Zikato Yes, that's sort of what I was thinking, so my first draft included that I wasn't sure whether this would be allowed…  But I guess someone changed it.  I'll add the tag trivia, then.

Comment: If no Tolkien fanatics happen across this riddle who know the reasoning to each line, I'll post the answer near the end of next week.  Also, if no one does better than rand al'thor, I'll make his answer the best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is:

> Gandalf.

*His raiment was the color of the king of Doriath's cloak,*

> Grey (when he was Gandalf the Grey). More detail: Elu Thingol is the king of Doriath, and Thingol is a Sindarin word coming from *sindacollo* meaning "grey cloak".

*But now is the color of the Spirit of Fire's prized creations.*

> White (he became Gandalf the White). The Spirit of Fire is Feanor, his creations being the white Silmarils.

*His weapon is from that which was betrayed by the Child of Twilight.*

> Glamdring (Gandalf's sword), which was forged in Gondolin. "Child of Twilight" is a translation of the name not given to Maeglin, who betrayed the location of Gondolin to her enemies. *Thanks to **Paul Rowe** for help with this clue.*

*His lords far out number his peers-*

> There are a lot more Valar (lords of the Wizards) in Middle-Earth than Maiar (Wizards). *Thanks to **Spacemonkey** for help with this clue.*

*-Them being only the Giver of Gifts and Aiwendil.*

> The Giver of Gifts is Saruman; Aiwendil is Radagast. (You've forgotten the two Blue Wizards out east though!)

*Now who could it be, tell me that?*

> GANDALF.

*And may the wind under your wings bear you

Where the sun sails and the moon walks.*

Quote:

> “Farewell," they cried, "Wherever you fare till your eyries receive you at the journey's end!" That is the polite thing to say among eagles.
> "May the wind under your wings bear you where the sun sails and the moon walks," answered Gandalf, who knew the correct reply.

Comment: What is the book's name?

Comment: You are pretty close, though I guess a more in-depth explanation is what I'm looking for.

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code - please tell me you're kidding!

Comment: Interestingly, this was my guess, despite not actually knowing the answer to any of the clues. I just went on the cloak changing colour...

Comment: @AndyT No I wasn't kidding. Okay, I Googled it right now, it's from *The Hobbit*. Maybe it could be added to the answer.

Comment: I think the Lords are meant to be the Valar and not the lords of men/elves. There are way more Valar than there are Wizards (because as Rand mentioned, there's only 5)

Comment: @AJL I've added more explanation. Good enough yet? :-)

Comment: I guessed the same answer after only the first clue. Not so difficult if you know the book(s).

Comment: @rand al'thor I like the effort :)  +1 for now, but I'll hold off on best answer.  Just wait a bit.

Comment: "Child of Twilight" is a translation of the name not given to Maeglin, who betrayed the location of Gondolin to her enemies. If memory serves, our character mentioned that his weapon and the other found with it were both forged in Gondolin.

Comment: @PaulRowe Thanks - I've edited my answer. Also thanks to Spacemonkey for help with the Valar thing. You've both been credited :-)

Comment: OK, I give up.  You win :-)

Comment: Oh, but the Spirit of Fire is Fëanor(that's what his name means), his prized creations being the white Silmarils.

Comment: @AJL Thanks - edited again. Should I credit you for that, since you're the OP?

Comment: Dunno, I'm a bit new here...  You can I guess